# Calendar - Get day of month AND month

Tags: android, android-calendar

So I have a simple calendar that I'm working on. I have it so that the current day is marked in blue. However, it will take the date (let's say today is the 3rd) and mark the 3rd of every month as blue. I think that the problem lies here;

```
// Current Month Days
for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {
    Log.d(currentMonthName, String.valueOf(i) + " "
            + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + " " + yy);
    if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
    } else {
        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can add like `if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth() + getMonth())` to get it to read the current month as well? Or is there another solution?

Comment: and an && operator and compare getMonth() to the currentMonth

Comment: Could you please give an example? I'm following a tutorial for this so I'm a little unfamiliar with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but something like this:

```
if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth() && getMonth() == currentMonth) {
```

Comment: I had to switch it to `if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth() && i == currentMonth) {` but this worked. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how that worked, since i is the day of the month, not the actual month. but if it works for you, then cool!

Comment: Ah. It worked because the day number (3) was the same as the month number. So... it didn't work! Will keep researching.

Comment: do what i originally answered